# How do I get mutliple files in useState in React(Next.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, array.prototype.map

First, please check out my code.

There might be some misspell! ( I rewrote my code )

```js
const test = () => {

  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const handleFile = (e) => {
  for(let i=0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
    setFiles([...files, e.target.files[i]
  }
}


return (


   {
   files.map((file, index) => (
       <div key={index}>
           <p>  {file[index].name}  </p>
           <button>  Delete  </button>
       </div>
   ))
   }

   <label onChange={handleFile}>
     <input type='file' mutiple /> Attach File
   </label>
)

}
```

When I render with this code, makes errors,

> TypeError: Cannot read Properties of undefined (reading 'name')
>
> {file[index].name}

like this.

When I delete .name, only buttons are being rendered. ( as I didn't specify what to render of file's property. )

Moreover, I'm trying to render multiple files at once. As I set my input type as **multiple**, I can select multiple files when I choose to upload things.

However, even though I selected two or three, It only renders just one.

I hope my explanation describes my situation well. If you have any questions, please ask me!

I'm looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: you should not setState in the rendering part of your function directly, you have to set it in a useEffect

Comment: @Ivo Alright Ivo, thank you!

Comment: sorry misread the code due to the alignment issue. your setState is actually in your onChange handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update the same state multiple time in the same handler function only the last call will work for performance issue. You have to change your onChange handler to something like:

```
const handleFile = (e) => {
   const newFiles = []
   for(let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++){
      newFiles.push(e.target.files[i])
   }
   setFiles(newFiles)
}
```

also as mentioned in another answer, change the "name" line to this:

```
<p>{file.name}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Ivo, However, I tried your statement, but it seems not working. IDK why, but I get empty array when I upload files.

Comment: sorry was a typo, not files.push but newFiles.push try with this.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the [index] part inside the map so should look like this

```
 <p>{file.name}</p>
```

Should work now :)

UPDATE FOR MULTIPLE UPLOADS

```
  const handleFile = (e) => {
    const newSelectedArray = files;
      newSelectedArray.push({
        ...e.target.files[0],
        identifier: e.target.filename  //check this please i cant remember what the array name is called for filename. You dont need this yet but once we get the first bit working we can include it in something cool.
      });
    setFiles(newSelectedArray)
}
```

Let me know on this one as it was a nightmare for me too so hopefully that will work

Comment: Thanks Matt! Now I can see my file names. However, I still can't render multiple files at once. When I selected two and three files and upload it, It only renders the first one. Do you know about this?

Comment: @AdenLee So you want to render a list of all the files uploaded is that right? Or you just want to change the current map to display the last uploaded file?

Comment: Yes. I want to render a list of all the files I uploaded. I'm trying a conditional statement to control it. However, if you know the efficient way, please let me know!

Comment: @AdenLee I understand. Came across a similar problem couple weeks ago so let me find my code and ill update my answer

Comment: Alright ! I'm having trouble still : /

Comment: @AdenLee Check now

Comment: Your answer is the same as Ivo, which works well. Thank you for sharing your answer. It was also my nightmare. : (

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same trouble as me, Here is a stopgap.

```js
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

     const handleFile = (e) => {
        setFiles([...files, e.target.files[0], e.target.files[1], e.target.files[2]])
        if(e.target.files[1] == null) {
            setFiles([...files, e.target.files[0]])
        } if (e.target.files[1] && e.target.files[2] == null) {
            setFiles([...files, e.target.files[0], e.target.files[1]])
        } 
    };
```

Using conditional statement, you can control the index of files. However, I still don't know what is the other way to deal with the problem.

Anyway, I hope my answer helps you some!

Comment: check my reply, should work and a bit cleaner ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i am missing out something, but I think looping like this is redundant when instead you can simply do

```
const handleFile = (e) => {
   setFiles(e.target.files)
}
```

Also, when you want to access the previous state value you should probably access the previous state value by using a callback function inside setFiles like this

```
for(let i=0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
    setFiles((prevfiles)=>[...prevFiles,e.target.files[i]])
}
```

EDIT:
I am also mentioning a fix not included in the original answer since it had already been stated by @Matt at the time of posting.I am editing this answer only for the sake of providing the complete answer

`file[index].name` had to be changed to `file.name`